# Other properties accessors besides 'set' and 'get'?

Tags: .net, clr

I was reflecting over properties of a type and wanted to check if a property has both a **public** setter and getter. Unfortunatly, `PropertyInfo`'s `CanRead` and `CanWrite` doesn't indicate the accessibility level. So I turned to `PropertyInfo.GetAccessors()` which has an [interesting description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff3b842x.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Returns an array whose elements reflect the public get, set, and **other accessors** of the property reflected by the current instance.

What 'other accessors' are there? Is there merely a possibility for other accessors, or does a CLI language exists that actually has more than the simple set/get duo for a property?

Comment: One way to find out. Create a property, decompile it, rename it (set to foo) and recompile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In real terms, there is just a getter and setter. Technically, IIRC the CLI spec (ECMA 335 section 1.8.11.3) doesn't *restrict* to just these, so some other language would be free to add other meanings, but in reality none do.

This is shown in table `II.17`, and uses the `.other` caption in IL (note it is `.get` for the getter, `.set` for the setter and `.custom` for attributes).

**edit**

*In particular*, note the example included in the specification:

```
  // the declaration of the property 
  .property int32 Count() { 
    .get instance int32 MyCount::get_Count() 
    .set instance void MyCount::set_Count(int32) 
    .other instance void MyCount::reset_Count() 
  }
```

This *suggests* that "reset" is an option; however, in reality this is handled via a reflection pattern; so for:

```
public int Foo {get;set;}
```

it is *convention* that `public void ResetFoo()` is the reset method for `Foo`, but the *compiler* does not process this into a custom accessor.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class MyType
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public void ResetFoo() { Foo = 0; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyType {Foo = 123};
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(MyType))["Foo"].ResetValue(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Foo); // outputs: 0

        var accessors = typeof (MyType).GetProperty("Foo").GetAccessors();
        // writes get_Foo and set_Foo
        foreach(var acc in accessors) Console.WriteLine(acc.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know about `ResetValue()` (I'm actually wholly unfamiliar with TypeDescriptor), but it make a lot of sense. Other than resetting a property, I can now think of a whole host of other possible accessors that can be implemented in properties: get default value, set without validation and get valid value range/list (for languages that have built-in verification constructs), subscribe and unsubscribe and set value without notifications (for languages that automatically implement change notifications à la `INotifyPropertyChanged`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfeventpgexample2) have `add` and `remove` accessors for registering delegates (that's what the `+=` gets translated to).

EDIT: Ok, they have little to do with properties, but they fall under the category of "other accessors". `EventInfo`, interestingly, has only methods like `GetAddMethod` and `GetRemoveMethod`.  Additionally, there's [`GetOtherMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7615ct5w.aspx) and `GetRaiseMethod`, but that's more dark magic I don't know much about...

Comment: Yes, but they don't apply to `PropertyInfo`

Comment: Personally I find it a bit strange that events weren't implemented as properties with different accessors.

Comment: Yes, technically the CLI spec for events includes `.addon`, `.removeon`, and **the interesting one**, `.fire`. However, C# neither **provides** nor **consumes** any `.fire` accessors. There is also, as with properties, `.other` (bespoke accessors) and `.custom` (actually attributes); these are shown in `II.18`, for reference

Comment: Interesting. It is eerily similar to properties, I wonder why the reflection APIs diverged in that way.

Comment: It'd actually make more sense to have a `GetGetterMethod()`, `GetSetterMethod()` and `GetOtherMethods()` on `PropertyInfo` instead of the rather odd `GetAccessors()`.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek They have those methods already for get and set: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17dw503.aspx (but nor for `other`, though)

Comment: @phg: Indeed they do! I must have missed them when going through the IntelliSense of `PropertyInfo`. Thanks!